# Criação de dois dicionários a partir de um dicionário com um critério

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, funções, lista

> Leia e armazene em um dicionário o nome, a idade e o número do telefone de seus contatos, sendo que a chave deve ser o nome. Ao digitar uma string vazia para o nome, o programa interrompe a leitura e se encerra.
> Apresente na tela os dados lidos em ordem alfabética pelo nome dos contatos. Uma possível solução de ordenar alfabeticamente é usar o método sort.
> Em seguida, armazene os contatos em outros dois dicionários, utilizando como critério a idade: menores de 18 anos em um e os maiores em outro dicionário, eliminando o original. Apresente na tela os dois dicionários resultantes da separação.
> Imprima na tela um teste do seu programa usando como primeiro cadastro o seu nome, como telefone o seu RU, e como idade os dois últimos dígitos do seu RU.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, estou totalmente perdido no que fazer a partir do primeiro passo.
Já resolvi até a parte em negrito no código abaixo. Não estou sabendo como fazer a parte de baixo, já pesquisei em tudo que é lado, sempre gera erro atrás de erro.

```
lista = []


while True:
    sair = input('Deseja cadastrar um contato ? [S/N]:')
    if sair == ' ':
        break
    nome = input('Qual o nome do contato?:')
    idade = int(input('Qual a idade?:'))
    tel= int(input('Qual o telefone do contato:?'))
    lista.append([nome,idade,tel])

print(lista)

listaordenada = sorted(lista)

for item in listaordenada:
    print('Nome:{}  Idade :{}  Telefone:{}'.format(item[0], item[1], item[2]))
```

Comment: O exercício pede para você armazenas os dados em um [dicionário](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) no seu programa está usando uma lista.

Answer (score 1):

Para separar um dicionário "d" em dois dicionários "d1" e "d2", à partir de uma "condicao", podemos usar "dict comprehensions":

```
d1 = {k:v for k, v in d.items() if condicao}
d2 = {k:v for k, v in d.items() if not condicao}
```

Ou, para percorrer o dicionário apenas uma vez:

```
d1 = {}
d2 = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    if condicao:
        d1[k] = v
    else:
        d2[k] = v
```

Portanto, a ideia é mais ou menos assim (os comentários são para chamar sua
atenção para as partes mais relevantes):

```
# Dicionário vazio (não confundir com um set vazio):
d = {}

while True:
    nome = input('Qual o nome do contato?:')
    # Interrompe execução se o nome for uma string vazia:
    if nome == '':
        break
    idade = int(input('Qual a idade?:'))
    tel = int(input('Qual o telefone do contato:?'))
    d[nome] = (idade, tel)

print(d)

# cria um dicionário ordenado pelas chaves:
sd = {k:d[k] for k in sorted(d)}

print(sd)

# menores_18 = {k:v for k, v in d.items() if v[0] < 18}
# maiores_18 = {k:v for k, v in d.items() if v[0] >= 18}

menores_18 = {}
maiores_18 = {}

for k, v in sd.items():
    if v[0] < 18:
        menores_18[k] = v
    else:
        # maior ou IGUAL a 18:
        maiores_18[k] = v

# Não "elimina" os originais, apenas "esquece" deles.
del d, sd

print(menores_18)
print(maiores_18)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
lista = []
list(lista)
dados = dict()
dadosm18 = dict()
lista18 = []
dados['nome'] = str(input('Nome: ')).title()
while dados['nome'] != '':
    dados['idade'] = int(input('Idade: '))
    dados['telefone'] = int(input('Telefone: '))
    lista.append(dados.copy())
    dados['nome'] = str(input('Nome: ')).title()
print(f'{"NOME":<15}{"IDADE":<10}{"TELEFONE":<10}')
for contatos in lista:
    print(f'{contatos["nome"]:<15}{contatos["idade"]:<10}{contatos["telefone"]:<10}')
if dados['idade'] < 18:
    lista18.append(dados.copy())
    print('-='*60)
    print('LISTA TELEFÔNICA COM DE MAIOR')
    print(f'{"NOME":<15}{"IDADE":<10}{"TELEFONE":<10}')
    for contatos1 in lista18:
        print(f'{contatos1["nome"]:<15}{contatos1["idade"]:<10}{contatos1["telefone"]:<10}')
```

A PRIMEIRA PARTE DEU BOM, SÓ A SEPARAÇÃO EM OUTROS DICIONÁRIOS QUE NÃO TÁ DANDO CERTO...